# Wrap a long string into many lines in datagridview column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a very long string in database(MS SQL) table such as

```
'99024','99050','99070','99143','99173','99191','99201','99202','99203','99204','99211','99212','99213','99214','99215','99217','99218','99219','99221','99222','99231','99232','99238','99239','99356','99357','99371','99374','99381','99382','99383','99384','99385','99386','99391','99392'
```

Right now it displays as in a datagridview of a windows form application.
[image: image 1]

What I expected is likely as (ignore the headtext, it doesn't matter).
[image: image 2]

Which means to split a long string to many short strings. Each string occupies one line.
Originally it was well done in asp.net gridview by the following code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("ICD9").ToString().Replace(",", Environment.NewLine.ToString())%>'
          Rows='<%# Eval("test").ToString().Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length %>'
             </asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
        <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("ICD9").ToString().Replace(",", Environment.NewLine.ToString())%>
   '>
                       </asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
```

Now I want to use it in windows form DataGridView, I don't know how to edit the column to customize the item. But I just thought that they could be similar.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows application, first of all you need to do is changing the DataGridView RowStyle so it can be auto sized based on your content

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.Fill;
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

then replace the comma by newline

```
Eval("test").ToString().Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: About replace the text, where is the right place? You copied my asp.net code. It is not correct.

Comment: Sorry man, I don't have Visual Studio here so I am not sure the syntax. But the aims is replacing the comma by a newline, so every single value appears on one line.